# Why might a file only be partially uploaded?

Tags: php, error-handling, upload, file-upload

Why might a file only be partially uploaded?

I am improving error-handling in my PHP file upload script and am trying to figure out how to handle UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL properly.

Should I prompt the user to try uploading the file again, or should I inform them that there is a more severe problem which is preventing them from uploading a possibly legitimate file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why might a file only be partially
>   uploaded?

This is usually caused by the user canceling the upload.

> Should I prompt the user to try
>   uploading the file again, or should I
>   inform them that there is a more
>   severe problem which is preventing
>   them from uploading a possibly
>   legitimate file?

You should prompt them to try again and if problems continue to contact the site owners, including as much detail as possible.

Comment: How should we handle this case on the client side with JS and on the server side with PHP? I mean, if the user starts an upload of a file and then clicks on a cancel button on the page while the file is still being uploaded, I can call `.abort()` how will PHP receive the information that the user canceled the upload?

Comment: "contact the site owners"???

Answer (score 26):

UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL is given when the mime boundary is not found after the file data. A possible cause for this is that the upload was cancelled by the user (pressed ESC, etc).

I think it's enough to inform the user that the file is only partially uploaded and a retry will fix the problem.

Comment: +1 for clarifying "when the mime boundary is not found after the file data"

Comment: @Seb Totally +1'd that one as well. Was running into a similar issue and that little side-note got me to the source. :)

Comment: In my case, I forgot the leading `--` on the last (in this case following) boundary. Lesson learned :-)

Comment: @halfdan - I'm not understanding why a mime boundary would be missing.  Doesn't PHP handle the boundaries? Alternatively, when a program saves a file (a PDF or pptx in my case), aren't the beginning and end of the file set by the program used?

Answer (score 10):

This is an old post, but I had a random problem of UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL, and post my solution.

The problem is that after 2/3 upload I obtained an error of UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL, without any interruption by the client.

My problem was related to the Keep-Alive server.

I solved it by inserting at the end of the PHP script for uploading

```
header ("Connection: close");
```

that forces the closure of the connection. This has solved my problem.

I hope someone can help.

Thank to this [LINK](http://www.bizzeh.com/739/php-problem-with-upload_err_partial-file-upload-error-code-3)

Comment: Worked for me! I spent hours thinking my script was failing / flakey seems that it was the server.

Comment: @Treemonkey happy to be useful ;-)

Comment: Duplicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425394/post-data-is-missing-when-posting-the-same-data-in-rapid-sequence

Comment: I see this answer given out a lot but it would be great if someone could explain why forcing keepalive to be disabled would work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the file upload could be interrupted by:

> Out of space in destination
>
> Connection interruption
>
> Damage file
>
> Wrong name
>
> Wrong extension
>
> etc...

The best you can do is to verify and protect the upload process with does verifications before actually send the file to the server...

The first time I've made a file upload script, I used 1 line of code, now, the same script seems like a web page ;)

EDITED (example for controlling extension and file size):

> if ((
>
> ```
> ($file_up["type"] == "image/gif") ||
>
> ($file_up["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
>
> ($file_up["type"] == "image/jpg") ||
>
> ($file_up["type"] == "image/pjpeg") ||
>
> ($file_up["type"] == "image/bmp") ||
>
> ($file_up["type"] == "image/tiff") ||
>
> ($file_up["type"] == "image/png")) &&
>
> ($file_up["size"] < 1050000))
>
> {
>
>     code if all ok...
>     
>     
> }
> ```

Comment: humm... yes, just imagine that your input should only be working with pictures and the user tries to upload a document, if it's supposed to be only pictures, you should deny any other file extensions (view my answer under the edit comment...

Comment: The question is how would a file name/extension cause a UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL?

Comment: well, it doesn't... the file extension was just a warning about possible errors that you might encounter... :)
Specifically to UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL, what Halfdan said seems to be the only reason... so, just inform the user that the process was interrupted, and should try again!

Answer (score 2):

This may help some people, but I had the same problem.
My solution was to uninstall libapache2-mod-php5filter and replace it with the classical libapache2-mod-php5

Answer (score 0):

I have a same problem and was related with package libapache2-mod-php5filter , I remove the p  and problem end.
I hope someone can help.

Comment: @yellowantphil looks like a borderline answer to me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today while working on an ajax file upload on my local machine until I realised(one hour later) that I had that same file (CSV) open in another program (MS Excel). Everything went back to normal after I closed the program in question.

Hope that helps !