# Which HTTP status code should be used for a UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL?

Tags: php, rest, http-status-codes

I'm developing a **[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) [API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/API)** and I have some **file uploads**:

PHP can generate an `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL` error when the file was only partially uploaded, and I'm not sure of which [HTTP status code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) should be used in this case.

This usually happens if the user cancels the upload (see [Why might a file only be partially uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937466/why-might-a-file-only-be-partially-uploaded) and [file upload errors on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) )

> UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL is given when the mime boundary is not found after the file data. A possibly cause for this is that the upload was cancelled by the user (pressed ESC, etc).

Comment: if the file is partially uploaded does it even execute your php code?

Comment: Yes, the thing is that when I detect the PHP error, I wan't to capture it and send the proper http status code back to the user.

Comment: i still don't understand your use-case, the only way it can happen is if the browser purposefully send partial data. because all the other types such as browser disconnect you will not be able to provide feedback

Comment: @DevZer0 I've updated the question, this can usually happen if the user cancels the upload.

Comment: Are you thinking of 206, "partial content"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should use 409 status code for this case.

According to http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt:

> The request could not be completed due to a conflict with the current 
>   state of the resource. This code is only allowed in situations where
>   it is expected that the user might be able to resolve the conflict
>   and resubmit the request. The response body SHOULD include enough
>   information for the user to recognize the source of the conflict.
>   Ideally, the response entity would include enough information for the 
>   user or user agent to fix the problem; however, that might not be
>   possible and is not required.

Answer (score 10):

If the user's upload failed because of something being wrong with what they're uploading, just say: `400 Bad Request`

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to send any status code, because client has already disconnected.

Comment: It's the good answer, in this case, the client will never receive the status code, so you can just do `exit();`

Answer (score 2):

I would go with either 422 (request unable to be followed due to semantic errors) or 449 (request should be retried after performing action).

Take a look at [httpstatuses.com](https://httpstatuses.com).

Answer (score 2):

> UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL is given *when the mime boundary is not found after the file data*.

**411 Length Required**

The request did not specify the length of its content, which is required by the requested resource

Answer (score 1):

i think the header should be based on error context:

if the file upload is not an allowed type:

- HTTP_415 = 'Unsupported Media Type'

if the file upload it too big:

- HTTP_413 = 'Request Entity Too Large'

if the server has a problem w/ the upload:

- HTTP_500 = 'Internal Server Error'

if the upload times out:

- HTTP_504 = 'Gateway Timeout'

but in general, i would say that **500** is pretty standard.

Comment: I know all this and **I already handle all of those**, I'm specifically asking about the `UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL` case

Comment: error `415` is not when the uploaded file is of non-allowed type. It is used when you use invalid `Content-Type` header. Also `5xx` errors are used to indicate error on server's side - but this is client's fault.

Answer (score -1):

I would use

**408** Request timeout. 
As it indicates that the request was only sent partially (which is not supported in this case)

**400** Bad Request 
looks like an other option.

You can also create your own using a non reserved number.

But where do you send the response if the request is cancelled?