# php5filter: Constantly getting UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL on files bigger than ~7961 Bytes

Tags: php, html, apache2, php-5.6

When i upload file bigger than 7961 Bytes (yes not MB, not KB, just Bytes) i get UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL. Sometimes the limit is a little bit greater like 7967B and so on. I am totally sure i have this in my php.ini (i checked it by running phpini()):

```
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M
max_execution_time = 30
memory_limit = 128M
file_uploads = On
```

I have tried to increase all values, but no effect.
When file is smaller, upload works normally.

My configuration is: apache2, apache2-mod-php5filter, php5 5.6.9.

Apache `error.log` tells.nothing. I have set `E_ALL`.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: don't forget apache limits. php's limits can NOT override those.

Comment: Are you passing lots of other fields along with FILE as they all take up space in the `post_max_size` allotted space

Comment: No I am testing it in simple form containing only one input for upload.

Comment: Is this any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937466/why-might-a-file-only-be-partially-uploaded

Comment: Thanks, no help. I am sure the file is uploaded whole, I checked request payload, and the file is there whole. So problem must be on server side. Server is on my localhost. So no trouble with bad connection.

Comment: I have solved it by installing apache2-mod-php5 instead of apache2-mod-php5filter. Any guess why php5filter can couse this?

Comment: @JaroslavPernica Check out the answer from lopezio: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35369564