# php upload file error code 3

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, freebsd

*Upload bigger file( > 10KB)* will get `error code 3(UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL) in $_FILES['file']['error']` and *small file( < 10KB)* will upload successfully.

If the file exceed the limit php **post_max_size** or **upload_max_filesize**, it should get `error code 1 UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE`. However, getting `error code 3 UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL` which is **incorrect**.

I guess it has something wrong with *apache setting*, and have no idea how to solve this problem.

Using below software and its versions

1. php 5.6.17
2. apache 2.4.18

*Following is the `php.ini`:*

```
post_max_size = 8M
file_uploads = On
upload_tmp_dir = "/tmp"
upload_max_filesize = 2M
```

and when upload larger file(hi.png) the error log in /var/log/httpd-error.log

```
PHP Notice:  Missing mime boundary at the end of the data for file hi.png in Unknown on line 0
```

here are index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Select image to upload:
    <input type='file' name='fileToUpload' id='fileToUpload'>
    <input type='submit' value='Upload Image' name='submit'>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and the upload.php

```
<?php
if($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] > 0){
    echo "error code".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['error']."<br>";
}
else{
    echo "file name:".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']."<br>";
    echo "file type:".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['type']."<br>";
    echo "file size:".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['size']."<br>";
    echo "file path:".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']."<br>";

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'],"uploads/".$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem in a FreeBSD 10.1 jail with php 5.6.18 and apache 2.4.18: Files above 7950 bytes would constantly and consistently fail with error 3, no matter which limits were set.

After ages I finally isolated the issue: The PHP module (mod_php56) was compiled with apache2filter SAPI but enabled as a handler via AddHandler. The solution was to **review the port options and rebuild mod_php56 with standard options (without AP2FILTER)**.

Long story: Check if you have port option `OPTIONS_FILE_SET+=AP2FILTER` (Apache 2 Filter SAPI) on, but PHP configured the usual way as a handler ( `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` ). Removing the option (as the default build/port does), and rebuilding the mod_php56 package solved the problem for me.

To verify if this is your case too, you can echo the `php_sapi_name()`. if it is `apache2filter` but php is enabled via `AddHandler` directive, you have the same problem. After rebuild, your php_sapi_name() should be **`apache2handler`**. Both options are also checkable in `phpinfo()`, as "Apache 2.0 Filter" and **"Apache 2.0 Handler"** respectively.

Note that this does not explain why it actually broke uploads (or why the module worked with the Handler configuration in the first place).
You might also succeed by enabling mod_php as a filter instead as a handler, but I did not check that here.

Comment: You, sir, deserve a gold medal for detecting this incredible error. I had pretty much the same issue on a very similar configuration, and, yes, mod_php56 was configured with AP2FILTER. Once it was recompiled without that 'experimental' option, everything worked again! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you! this was a track to follow while spend 8+ hours on researching after Debian 7 wheezy upgrade to 8 Jessie - somehow apache mod_php5filter installed instead of mod_php5 and from this answer here http://serverfault.com/questions/341869/apache2-and-php5-module-or-filter we can see that not all things are passed to filter!