# Delete partially uploaded files PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

I wrote a upload script to upload files in PHP. suppose if some client upload files and those got uploaded partially or failed during upload. I wonder what happens to the file on the server. Does it get deleted ? I am really confused how to handle those partial uploads. Does PHP handle them ?

Any help is accepted

Comment: Check this post, might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937466/why-might-a-file-only-be-partially-uploaded

Comment: thanks @Mark Frakii for the suggestion.

Comment: Uploaded files are temporary files and only exist on the server until the PHP script ends. If you haven't done anything with them, complete or partial, they will "go away" after your script ends.